# Solr synonym replacement fails?

Tags: solr

I have a **SynonymFilterFactory** using a synonym file. From the Solr documentation:

```
#Explicit mappings match any token sequence on the LHS of "=>"
#and replace with all alternatives on the RHS.  These types of mappings
#ignore the expand parameter in the schema.
#Examples:
i-pod, i pod => ipod,
sea biscuit, sea biscit => seabiscuit
```

However, when querying `sea biscuit`, I end up with results related to `sea`, `biscuit` and `seabiscuit`.

This is *as if I* had the following configuration (with `expand="true"`):

```
sea biscuit, sea biscit, seabiscuit
```

I don't understand this behavior, because in the Solr analysis tool, when querying `sea biscuit` it is properly replaced by `seabiscuit` only.

In other words: **explicit synonym mapping with `=>` doesn't work**.

---

### Edit: field configuration

Tokenized: `true`

Class Name: `org.apache.solr.schema.TextField`

**Index** Analyzer: `org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain`

- Tokenizer Class: `org.apache.solr.analysis.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`

Filters:

```
org.apache.solr.analysis.StopFilterFactory args:{enablePositionIncrements: true words: stopwords.txt ignoreCase: true }
org.apache.solr.analysis.WordDelimiterFilterFactory args:{preserveOriginal: 1 catenateWords: 1 catenateNumbers: 1 splitOnCaseChange: 1 catenateAll: 0 generateNumberParts: 1 generateWordParts: 1 }
org.apache.solr.analysis.LowerCaseFilterFactory args:{}
org.apache.solr.analysis.SnowballPorterFilterFactory args:{protected: protwords.txt }
org.apache.solr.analysis.LengthFilterFactory args:{min: 2 max: 500 }
org.apache.solr.analysis.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory args:{}
org.apache.solr.analysis.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory args:{}
```

**Query** Analyzer: `org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain`

- Tokenizer Class: `org.apache.solr.analysis.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`

Filters:

```
org.apache.solr.analysis.LowerCaseFilterFactory args:{}
org.apache.solr.analysis.SynonymFilterFactory args:{expand: true ignoreCase: true synonyms: synonyms.txt }
org.apache.solr.analysis.StopFilterFactory args:{words: stopwords.txt ignoreCase: true }
org.apache.solr.analysis.WordDelimiterFilterFactory args:{preserveOriginal: 1 catenateWords: 0 catenateNumbers: 0 splitOnCaseChange: 1 catenateAll: 0 generateNumberParts: 1 generateWordParts: 1 }
org.apache.solr.analysis.SnowballPorterFilterFactory args:{protected: protwords.txt }
org.apache.solr.analysis.LengthFilterFactory args:{min: 2 max: 500 }
org.apache.solr.analysis.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory args:{}
org.apache.solr.analysis.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory args:{}
```

Comment: Could you post your field configuration ?

Comment: @rohk Done, I posted the configuration of the type of the field I use

Answer (score 1):

SynonymFilterFactory has been deprecated and should now be replaced with [SynonymGraphFilterFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-SynonymFilter). It squashes tokens and fixes issues with multi-word synonyms when more than one token exist at the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a phrase query (using double-quotes) ?
If not, you are giving two different tokens to the SynonymFilter (sea and biscuit). In that case, no matching synonym is found.

By the way, it's almost always a better idea to handle synonyms at index time. Look here : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory

Comment: I am not using double quotes, but however it seems that synonyms with spaces work when there is, for example, `this chocolate, that chocolate` (and no `=>`).. So why wouldn't that work here?

Comment: Regarding the index time usage of the synonyms, I've read that earlier, you're right, but I can't (unfortunately) change it right now).